# Azure DevOps Pipeline publish a ClickOnce application in different environment?

Tags: xml, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to deploy an ClickOnce application with Azure DevOps Pipeline (Continuous Integration first then Continuous Deployment).

I could run the CI part from Azure DevOps. In fact I can also do the CD part on my staging environment. During the CI I generate a M.m.B.r build number that is compatible with assembly format requested by ClickOnce.

But I have 2 environment and I need to consider staging and production. For that I would like to modify the name of the application that is the *.application file. If you don't change the name then when you install the staging then the production on your computer this one think it is the same application.

I'm looking for a task that can modify and XML based on my Pipeline variables.

I found this list

[image]

but all these tasks seems limited to xml config file. The microsoft version, I already tested, can only change the connection string or the app settings section.

What should I use?

Comment: I found a workaround with RegEx Replace tasks.

Comment: Would it be an option to use Powershell to rename the file? It's easy to implement.

Comment: Yes it can be an option also. But now I found that you cannot modify de *.config.deploy file because you invalid the control key of the ClickOnce system. So the only solution I found is to create 2 build at same time. One for staging, one for production and I deploy the correct build to the correct environment. I juts don't like the idea to create 2 similar build but I have no choice.